# DNS for Google Site (No Web Addresses)

Tags: google-sites

I try to link the GoDaddy DNS with Google Site.
I found following instructions:
[Use your domain as a custom URL for your Google Site](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6069257?hl=en-GB)  (it looks obsoleted already - no DNS tab in My Domains section: there is "Advanced DNS settings" drop-down panel with link to GoDaddy: "Sign in to DNS console" ) 
[GoDaddy: Forward Your Domain to Work with Google Sites](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/forward-your-domain-to-work-with-google-sites-6031)

The question is that: Why I don't see "Web Addresses" option in "Manage Site":
It should be like this:
[image: Web Addresses]
But I have the next situation (No Web Addresses):
[image: My case: No Web Addresess]
Also I can find my site by domain but I see in the browser the full URL: "https://sites.google.com/a/domain/site-name".

Answer (score 1):

You can not use domain mapping for Google Site Free Edition. You should upgrade it to G Suite.

If you are using G Suite, you could setting domain mapping with this steps:

1. Click Gear icon then click Manage Site
   [image: Manage Site Menu]
2. Scroll to down and fine button **Map this site**
   [image: Map Site Menu]
3. Enter Your sub domain you want to mapped to Google Site
   [image: Add New Mapping domain]
4. Add cname to your DNS record with google host
   [image: Cname Google Host]

Hope this answer your question.

Cheers

Comment: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2518318 - Customize a Google Site address. Sorry, please, I had a chat with Google Support and they explained me what to do.

Comment: So, do you solve your problem now? I explained to you how to customize Google Site for domain mapping. It is need Google Suite account to do that. I am trying on my Google site free edition but can not found domain mapping feature then i trying Google Site on my Google Suite Package and found domain mapping feature there. Did my explanation not answer your question?

Comment: You do not need edit dns record on Google site. Just add cname record ghs.googlehosted.com as address and www or other sub domain as value/alias on DNS management. You could find DNS management at Godaddy.